# No message on item removal

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, quote

I am facing below issue:

I have added couple of products (say P1 and P2) in cart. Now I have disabled P2 from admin.
Now when I am visiting the checkout page by clicking the checkout link, Magento removes the disabled product from quote but it does not display any message for it.

How can I show the item removal message in this scenario?